# A different kind of mouselook script?

Tags: scripting, game-engine

Is there a mouselook script that's exactly the same as the classic one except it moves left and right, not up and down. If there isn't one then can you show a property hook script that enables/disables up and down rotation.

Comment: Are you referring to the mouse wheel up/down? I don't think wheel left/right is supported. What about mouse movement? - that gives you 4 directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mouse move script](http://riyuzakisan.weebly.com/mousemove-script.html#toc) allows cutomization. In order to restrict up/down rotation you could add the properties as shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot, I just have one tiny thing which I feel stupid about since I can't fix it. I needed this for the collision bounds(ml.cap). Everytime I hit "P," the character in the collision bounds flips over when I move my mouse, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @TheBasicTroublemaker The P key is not bound to an action in the demo, this is probably an issue in your scene, you could  add a few print statements to find out where the character flips.

Comment: Would it be okay if I give you the .blend, and you can see the prob?

Comment: @TheBasicTroublemaker I don't have much experience with the BGE but you could ask that as another question and add the .blend file there.

Comment: Oh, well thanks thought! Really appreciate it.