# Mouselook script needed

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have looked everywhere and I cannot find a good mouselook script that **limits the up and down rotation of the camera**.  I've already found many scripts that do not limit it. I want one that stays steady and does not wobble one you are not moving your mouse.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/a-different-kind-of-mouselook-script

Comment: http://riyuzakisan.weebly.com/mousemove-script.html, has everything you could need. Instructions, a download with a .blend, etc.